# Implicit return value and compile errors in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider the following code in a class in ruby:

```
 def isDarkSide
     true
 end
```

The return value of `isDarkSide` is true

However, when I run `ruby -c` on the following code:

```
  def can_join_group? any
    DeathStar::Tie::BOT, self, nil
  end
```

I endup with the following errors:

> ```
> dynamic constant assignment
>     DeathStar::Tie::BOT, self, nil
>                                ^
> Can't change the value of self
>    DeathStar::Tie::BOT, self, nil
>                                      ^
> Can't assign to nil
> syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting '='
> ```

However, the problem can be fixed by writing

```
  def can_join_group? any
    return DeathStar::Tie::BOT, self, nil
  end
```

Can someone explain to me why do I need to use the return keyword ? I feel like I'm missing something important in ruby language.

Answer (score 2):

To return multiple values, you should use either explicit `return` or array of values.

Also `1, 2, 3` is not even a valid Ruby syntax.

```
def multi_return1
  return 1, 2, 3
end

def multi_return2
  [1, 2, 3]
end

multi_return1 == multi_return2
#=> true
```

Comment: you were like few seconds faster :)